# Aphids in my greenhouse

Tags: aphids

I am growing bok choy, spinach, radish, snap peas, lettuce etc in my small 6' x 10' greenhouse here in the cold Northeast. All growing well, but I've picked up an infestation of aphids on my spinach and bok. I've used insecticidal soap at least 4 times over 10 days and they still seem to multiplying. Help!

Comment: This website sucks

Comment: Photos would have helped

Comment: Aphids in a greenhouse really suck. From experience even keeping aphid numbers low will be hard.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered introducing ladybugs to your greenhouse?

https://www.planetnatural.com/aphids-ladybugs/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).